# Wordpress next/prev post on single custom post page?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

So I've got a custom post type, all working fine.

Goes to single-portfolio, but it won't paginate.

I can't, no matter what I try get pagination to work on the single page.

Here's my code.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="main-content">





    <div class="portfoliopost">

    <div class="col-full">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">


            <div class="port-left-single">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <div class="projecttype">
                                    <ul>
                                     <?php
                                        $posttags = get_the_tags();
                                        if ($posttags) {
                                          foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                                            echo '<li>' .$tag->name. '</li>'; 
                                          }
                                        }
                                        ?>

                                    </ul>   

                    </div>
                <?php the_field('main_portfolio_meta'); ?>
            </div> <!-- end div port-left-single -->

            <div class="port-right-single">
            <?php the_content(); ?>


            </div>  










                <div style="clear:both;"></div>



        </div> <!-- end div post-class -->

                <div class="navigation">
            <div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('Older Posts') ?></div>
            <div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts') ?></div>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>


    </div> <!-- end div col-full -->    
    </div> <!-- end div portfolipost -->    







<div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div> <!-- end div main content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It's inside the loop, so what gives?

Comment: Are you sure you have more than 1 post published? Check also pagination settings in WordPress options.

Comment: Yes, I have a bunch published, I sort of know what I'm doing, kind of...

Pagination is working on the main blogroll page, just not with custom posts.